# Using a file located in either the raw or assets folder

Tags: android

Currently I am able to download a file off the internet and store on the SD card, then use the file from there. However that makes the file (with proprietary data) available to be seen. I would prefer to use the file from somewhere like raw or assets folder. 
I will skip the downloading code, but my code to use the file is this

```
  File myFile = new File (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder/filename.xml");
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  myIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(myFile));
```

Android opens the file with the default application and all is good.

I have found similar Q/A's that revolve around using code like

```
  Uri.parse("android.resource://com.projectname.testing/raw/filename");
```

and

```
  InputStream ins  = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);
```

but I can't work out how to get either of those two back into a 'file' format to be used with my .setData code

I would like to solve my problem by simply accessing the file as a file. However since it is being used by an external application I have read I might need to make a temporary copy of the file with mode_world_readable then delete it after the application closes. This sounds like a lot of extra work, especially since my code above does work for a file stored on the SD card.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would prefer to use the file from somewhere like raw or assets folder.

Note that these too can be "seen".

> but I can't work out how to get either of those two back into a 'file' format to be used with my .setData code

`setData()` does not take a `File`. It takes a `Uri`. Use `Uri.parse()` to parse other types of `Uri` values -- you already have this code shown above.

> However since it is being used by an external application I have read I might need to make a temporary copy of the file with mode_world_readable then delete it after the application closes.

It definitely will need to be world-readable. Also, not all apps support all schemes, so apps that support `file://` or `http://` might not support `android.resource://`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate on how files in the raw or assets folders can be seen? I thought they were encoded and packed into the .apk which would require 'hacking' to break into (thus if someone were to have my private data it would prove 'illegal activity' to gain) - Also, I have tried all kinds of different Uri.parse options but nothing seems to work. It only works when I pass a File.

Comment: @lifeIsGood: "Can you elaborate on how files in the raw or assets folders can be seen?" -- these are world-readable to other apps.